# Value of selectone menu passed through Autocomplete not not being recieved in managed bean

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a datable to which i can dynamically add rows on click the add button.

```
<p:dataTable id="ListTable" styleClass="hide-column-names"
             value="#{sManagedBean.View.pList}"
             var="p" rowIndexVar="rowIndex">
    <p:column>
        <p:inputText id="pInput" required="#{not empty param[saveButton.clientId]}" value="#{p.name}" />
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:selectOneMenu id="pSs" value="#{p.sp}">
            <p:ajax update="pComplete" global="false" />
            <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="0"/>
            <f:selectItems value="#{sManagedBean.pList}" var="sp" itemValue="#{sp.id}" itemLabel="#{sp.title}" />
        </p:selectOneMenu>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:autoComplete id="pComplete" value="#{p.ptitle}" required="#{not empty param[saveButton.clientId]}" completeMethod="#{sManagedBean.pComplete}" global="false" minQueryLength="3">
            <p:ajax event="query" global="false" />
            <f:attribute name="filter" value="#{p.sp}" />
        </p:autoComplete>
    </p:column>
    <p:column>
        <p:commandLink value="Delete" id="delete"
                       actionListener="#{sManagedBean.removeFromList}"
                       update="ListTable pSs"  
                       rendered="#sManagedBean.oView.ptList.size()>'1'}">
            <f:param name="rowToRemove" value="#{rowIndex}" /> 
        </p:commandLink>
    </p:column>
</p:dataTable>
<h:outputText/>
<p:commandLink id="addPLink" value="Add"
               style="font-weight:bold;"
               actionListener="#{sManagedBean.AddP}"
               update="ListTable growlQ" global="false">
    <h:graphicImage value="../images/addbutton.jpg" />
</p:commandLink>
```

The managed Bean is

```
public List<String> pComplete(int query) {
    FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
    int sId = Integer.parseInt(UIComponent.getCurrentComponent(context).getAttributes().get("filter").toString());
    System.out.println("s " + sId);
    Session session = null;
    List<String> result = null;
    try {
        session = hibernateTemplate.getSessionFactory().openSession();
        result = session.createSQLQuery("select title from pb where title like : alphabets and sId =:sId").setString("alphabets", query + "%").setInteger("sId", sId + 1).list();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        log.warn("FL Warning", e);
    }
    return result;
}
```

but the value passed through autocomplete is always zero.

I am not able to get the value of selectone menu of a corresponding row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got the answer i added ajax in between the selectone menu

```
<p:ajax event="change" update="pComplete"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

This should do the work:

```
<p:column>
    <p:selectOneMenu id="pSs" value="#{p.species}">
        <p:ajax update="pComplete" global="false" />
        <f:selectItem itemLabel="Select" itemValue="0"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{sManagedBean.pList}" var="sp" itemValue="#{sp.id}" itemLabel="#{sp.title}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu>
</p:column>
<p:column>
    <p:autoComplete id="pComplete" value="#{p.ptitle}" required="#{not empty param[saveButton.clientId]}" completeMethod="#{sManagedBean.pComplete}" minQueryLength="3">
        <p:ajax event="query" global="false" />
        <f:attribute name="filter" value="#{p.species}" />
    </p:autoComplete>
</p:column>
```